# RegEx help in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have really looked for an answer to my problem but I can't seem to find it. So forgive me if I create a duplicate here.

My issue is that I'm creating a script and I need to validate a username and I realize that this has to be done using a regular expression; which I suck in.

- Can contain any character; even local like russian, chinese, greek, swedish etc.
- Can contain underscores, hyphens and dots.
- Can contain numbers
- Can contain only one single whitespace.

What usernames can **not** contain, is the following:

```
! " # ¤ % & / ( ) = ? ` \ ´ ' ^ ~ ¨ § | @ £ $ € { [ ] }`
```

So how in the world one do create a regex based on this is beyond my skills. I haven't found a single question/answer that has the same requirements. I would be over-happy for help on creating this regex, guys.

Comment: See "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" in [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't find a good way of formatting the heading. But I will change it.

Comment: _this has to be done using a regular expression_ - why? if you have a blacklist of characters you can just check for each with `strstr`.

Comment: Halcyon: I just thought that a regex was the best solution...(?)

Comment: @FredoSk - `Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
^(?:[\x{2D}\x{2E}\x{5F}\p{L}\p{N}]+)(?: (?:[\x{2D}\x{2E}\x{5F}\p{L}\p{N}]+))$
```

\x{2D} ... Match the character -
\x{2E} ... Match the character .
\x{5F} ... Match the character _
\p{L} ... Match any Unicode Letter.
\p{N} ... Match any Unicode Number.

---

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:[\x{2D}\x{2E}\x{5F}\p{L}\p{N}]+)(?: (?:[\x{2D}\x{2E}\x{5F}\p{L}\p{N}]+))$/usim', $subject)) {
    # Successful match
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pattern = '/[^\!\¤\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\`\\\^\~\¨\§\|\@\£\$\€\{\[\]\}\"\']+/';
preg_match($pattern, "test test test");
```

Should do the trick. This creates actually a white list. It checks the string for all but these characters, but the `^` is responsible for this. It should return 1 when the string has `normal` characters and 0 when the string contains one of the black listed characters.

To check for whitespaces do an extra preg_match.

```
$pattern = '/^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/';
preg_match($pattern, "test test test");  //should return 0.
```

Comment: Thanks. Still, it gives me a code error. Here's the code with your regex implemented:

if(preg_match(/[^\!\"\#\¤\%\&\/\(\)\=\?\`\\\´\'\^\~\¨\§\|\@\£\$\€\{\[\]\}]/g, $username)) {
echo 'bla bla bla'; exit;
}

I guess the quoting gives the error

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a two step, check for any matches with this `preg_match_all` and `preg_quote`(RegEx):
(Will return number of matches)

```
$pattern = preg_quote("!\"#¤%&()=?`´'^~¨§|@£$€{[]}]");
preg_match_all("/[$pattern]/", $password);
```

And then count spaces in the password:
[substr-count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)

```
int substr_count ($password , " ");
```

Putting it all together

```
$pattern = preg_quote("!\"#¤%&()=?`´'^~¨§|@£$€{[]}]","/");
if (!preg_match_all("/[$pattern]/", $password) and (substr_count ($password , " ") < 2)) {
    //Pasword is OK
    echo "Works!\n";
} else {
    //Password has issues
    echo "Does not work :( \n";
}
```

Or using the more effective [strpbrk](http://php.net/strpbrk) (returns the string after the first character match from the pattern):

```
$pattern = "!\"#¤%&()=?`´'^~¨§|@£$€{[]}]";
if (!strpbrk($password,$pattern) and (substr_count ($password , " ") < 2)) {
    //Pasword is OK
    echo "Works!\n";
} else {
    //Password has issues
    echo "Does not work :( \n";
}
```

Good luck from Richard, Bergen :D

Comment: Hey, Richard! Thanks, I will try your suggestion now and come back :)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in...

Comment: add ' to the regex string :/

Comment: Sory way to late for this, slight change in the code, added " instead of ' and a \" in the code :)

Comment: Gives me:

Notice: Undefined variable: â‚¬ in...
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in

Comment: Check out the last one, actually works :D

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort to help me, Richard. Though, Andie gave me the fix and it works as a charm :)

Comment: No worries, glad you got it working :)